# Equivalence between Basic Relational Algebra

Tags: relation-algebra

The following relation schema: R(**A**,C), S(**A**,D), T(**X**,Y). Primary key attributes bolded

Would like to know why the following two are not equivalent queries

$Q_1 = π_A (σ_{C<10}(R))$ and $Q_2 = σ_{C<10}(π_A(R))$

The answer: $Q_2$ Invalid expression as the selection condition refers to a non-existent attribute. I'm not sure what the answer means. $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ looks similar but $Q_2$ is invalid.

Could anyone provide some values and examples to explain? Thanks!

Comment: $\pi_A$ projects the table $|A|C|$ onto the table $|A|$. The second table has no $C$-entry anymore. Thus you can't apply the selection to this table.

Comment: I see! So the primary key attribute doesn't affect the question here?

Comment: No, it doesn't :)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! It was very helpful. :)